# Noisy Postgres Postgis Adapter Rails Database Migrations Testing

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to setup Postgres and Postgis to do some simple geo operations in my app.  I am following the directions from [this post](http://ngauthier.com/2013/08/postgis-and-rails-a-simple-approach.html).  Everything is working great and fast.  However when i run `rake db:migrate` or `rake test` I get the following errors:

```
psql:/Users/jophde/Desktop/local/db/structure.sql:154: ERROR:  rule "geometry_columns_delete" for relation "geometry_columns" already exists
psql:/Users/jophde/Desktop/local/db/structure.sql:161: ERROR:  rule "geometry_columns_insert" for relation "geometry_columns" already exists
psql:/Users/jophde/Desktop/local/db/structure.sql:168: ERROR:  rule "geometry_columns_update" for relation "geometry_columns" already exists
```

They are more like warnings since tests and migrations work fine.  However, it is very annoying to have this printed out every time I test.  I am using `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`.  Here are the line referenced in the errors in `structure.sql`

```
CREATE RULE geometry_columns_delete AS ON DELETE TO geometry_columns DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
CREATE RULE geometry_columns_insert AS ON INSERT TO geometry_columns DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
CREATE RULE geometry_columns_update AS ON UPDATE TO geometry_columns DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

My database configuration is as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: local_development
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: local_test
  host: localhost
```

The migrations I am using to enable PostGis are:

```
class EnablePostgis < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    enable_extension :postgis
  end
end

class AddPointIndexToMarkets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute %{
      create index index_on_markets_location ON markets using gist (
        ST_GeographyFromText(
          'SRID=4326;POINT(' || markets.longitude || ' ' || markets.latitude || ')'
        )
      )
    }
  end

  def down
    execute %{ drop index index_on_markets_location }
  end
end
```

I am using Postgres.app Version 9.3.0.0 (16) (The newest) on Mac OSX 10.8.4 (Mountain Lion)

Answer (score 1):

Try `ActiveRecord::Schema.verbose = false`

Comment: Where would I set this at in my application?  I can't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: You could add it to one of your initializer files

Comment: Doesn't seem to working.  I think psql needs silenced specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

`min_messages: fatal`

to `development` and `test` in `config/database.yml` did the trick.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: local_development
  host: localhost
  min_messages: fatal

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: local_development
  host: localhost
  min_messages: fatal
```